# Kendo adds instead of editing a DropdownList item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, selected, selectedvalue

I use Kendo grid inline editing mode and after editing I need to refresh datasource for my DropDownList.

The reason is my KendoGrid is supposed to add and edit data that my DropDownList uses.
I have no problem on editing data on KendoGrid and with the help of the code below I refresh the data on the DropDownList.

```
var dropDownList = $("#Domains").data("kendoDropDownList");
                    dropDownList.dataSource.read();
```

`#Domains` is the ID of my DropDownList

Everything work just fine even if I edit the data that is already selected on the DropDownList .
But the problem comes after adding new item in the KendoGrid (Inline Mode) and editing one of the older items which is selected on the DropDownList at the same time.

In this situation Kendo doesn't edit the item but It Adds edited item as a new item to the data source and we will have the old item and the edited one as two separate items.
I don't know if I convey the situation correctly.

I use MVC and the way I define datasource is like this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                            .Ajax()
                                            .Events(events => { events.Error("result_handler"); })
                                            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                                            .Create(create => create.Action("AddDomain", "Service", new { customerID = ViewBag.CustomerId }))
                                            .Read(read => read.Action("GetDomainListForGrid", "Service", new { customerID = ViewBag.CustomerId }))
                                            .Update(update => update.Action("EditDomain", "Service"))
                                            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DeleteDomain", "Service"))
                                        )
```

As you see I set model.Id like the above.

Comment: What do you use as `id` in your model for this _updated_ entry?

Comment: I Updated my text with my answer in the end.

Comment: KendoUI decides between create and update depending on the value of the id, that's why I ask about what were you using. Did you check that the `id` for old records are actually correct (before adding a new item is the same that after)?

Comment: The easiest way is defining a column in the grid for displaying the id.

Comment: Well now I checked and It just give "0" to the Id. How can I update that?
Do I need to call ".dataSource.read()" for the grid too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23087/discussion-between-onabai-and-sabox)

Answer (score 0):

Not a great idea! but refreshing the data on grid before selecting the DropDownList item would help:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                    grid.dataSource.read();
```